# Matching hashed password with db password for login sha256 with pepper

Tags: php, hash, passwords, sha256

It is my understanding reg and login (on a very basic level) work like this...

On registration the password is hashed then sent to the db.

On login the inputted password is hashed using the same hash function then compared using `password_verify` for a match before procceding.

With this in mind i wrote a php hash function (based on a comment I found at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#124138 (I have changed pepper detail for this example)

hash function..

```
function shashpw($ppw) {
$pepper = "DXmdpEcFwc1dm3jlvxiSVf";
$pwd_peppered = hash_hmac("sha256", $ppw, $pepper);
$pwd_hashed = password_hash($pwd_peppered, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID);
return $pwd_hashed;
}
```

Example input and outputs..

```
$pw = "#Hqq20";
echo shashpw($pw);
//output examples..
$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$YVozcUxkdWVCemN2OHh2Qg$KUgtrw+yJL6mH9D7besewB2pf6KHxUpxeX12DDPX4ms
$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$QXYuckpPYy43YlRmQlZmUw$6qd5Vwn6ac3yr4X3MwRksFZ8GleHotjhgfeavY0f5cg
```

So you get a new hash each time you run the function, great however there in lies my problem.

If i run the same password hash function at the login on the user inputted password for checking against the db stored at reg password hash they will never match, as the hash is new everytime. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: simply use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify

Comment: You read the stored salt is part of the hash calculation. If you use that salt, you should get the same hash.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Re: You read the stored salt is part of the hash calculation.  How?

Comment: How do I extract just the salt part from my hash function above?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I am using password_verify but it never matches as the hash is differant everytime! From what I've read thats what i need for it to be differant everytime and that password_verify is supposed to handle that but is never a match thus not working for me.

Comment: You will have to apply the pepper in the same way you did before calling password_hash(), but then you test it with password_verify(). Make sure your database field, which stores the hashes, is long enough varchar(255).